# KnockoutJS - printing html snippets

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to render a new div with the class `row-fluid` on every 4th object in my observableArray.  Unfortunately putting html snippets into an if block doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
<!-- ko foreach: detailsVm.addresses -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 === 0 -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div class="span4">
        My Content
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 === 0 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: is your goal to have 3 columns in a single row (so, don't close the div until you have added the next two)?

Comment: Thanks Ryan - looks like the problem is that $index needs to be unwrapped. @rpn

Comment: Ryan - yeah, I'm trying to only open and close the div on every third item - but stuff still is odd - are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?  @rpn

Comment: `$index` is an observable, so it definitely needs to be unwrapped.  KO needs the elements to be balanced (opened/closed properly), so doing the partial snippets does not work.  I have a couple of alternatives that I can write up quick for you.

Comment: @rpn - Any hints you could write up would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @rpn - my best guess would be to put "My Content" into a template, then render it in a row-fluid that's visible if index % 3, and render it without the row-fluid otherwise.  Is that your best suggestion?  If so I'll just run with that.

Comment: I think that you will have an issue with nesting in that case.  You can't open and close the row-fluid within the same item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of (not awesome) ways to go with this one:

Normally, I would suggest mapping your array to a structure that is more suitable for binding in your view.  So, you would map it to a row/cell structure.  Then, you can easily loop through the rows/cells to produce your output.  Like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EdXA2/

A little messier, but you could even do:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 === 0 -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <!-- ko with: $parent.items()[$index() + 1] -->
        <div class="span4" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko with: $parent.items()[$index() + 2] -->
        <div class="span4" data-bind="text: name"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pfzpq/

One idea for a custom binding would be to create a binding that takes in a array and a number of columns and splits it into smaller arrays for you.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sHDnR/.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.arrayToRows = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, all, vm, context) {
        var rows = ko.computed(function() {
            var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()),
                data = options.data,
                count = options.count,
                rows = [], row;

            for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (i % count === 0) {
                    if (row) {
                        rows.push(row);
                    }
                    row = [];
                }
                row.push(data[i]);
            }

            //push the final row  
            if (row) {
                rows.push(row);
            }

            return rows;

        }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: rows });

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

I have one other thought where the custom binding would wrap the elements after the fact.  Might give that a shot when I have more time.

Comment: We went with fixed-width floating divs and solved everything at once :)  Thank you a ton for the code though - I'll definitely keep this in mind for then next time something like this comes up

Answer (score 1):

I know you've fixed it, but a thought for the future: would it be harmful in your context to have that wrapper div always present, but only have a "fluid" class present on every 4th row? Because if not, even though I hate rendering needless markup, in iteration situations like this sometimes I find it easier to just use CSS. Something like:

.container .row:nth-child(4n) { Your fluid styles }

Comment: That's a good thought, but these styles are all pre-built using Twitter Bootstrap. Otherwise I'd be open to something like that